# How to sent data by ajax in multiple urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

For my script I want to send few data in multiple `url's` by `ajax` for multiple `php` query. So I tried as below which not call ajax `waitForRep()`. How to do it please?

my Javascript:

```
var url = ['/server/server2','/server/server'];
var tutid = '<?php echo $tutid; ?>';
var CID = '<?php echo $id; ?>';

function waitForRep(){
    $.each(url, function(i,u){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            data: {
            tutid : tutid,
            CID : CID
        },
            timeout:15000, 
            success: function(data){ 
                // do something with result
                setTimeout(waitForRep, 15000 );
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                setTimeout(waitForRep, 15000); 
            }
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    waitForRep();
});
```

Comment: Where are the variables tutid and CID coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with `setTimeOut`. It looks like you're trying to call the ajax twice.

If you want to call the second ajax  on success, there's no need to iterate through the array. Simply call another ajax on the first ajax success.

Get rid of `$.each` and do it like this:

```
$.ajax ({
  url: link1
  success: function (data){
    $.ajax ({
      url: link2
     });
  });
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to send multiple requests to multiple URLs: just send each by the same `request`, `params`...

But if you want to handle responses after sending all requests, the first idea in my mind to solve this is `Promise`, I tried with native Promise and [it worked](https://jsfiddle.net/ucswc2z1/), but if you prefer `jQuery`, I suggest you have a look on [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/), this one maybe what you're looking for ( check the deferred part).